# ¿Como agregar parametros al metodo EventHandler que se agrega al evento Click en C#?

Tags: c#, eventos

Resulta que estoy empezando a programar en C#, bueno, mi problema es que yo tengo una matriz de Button y al inicializar los botones les agrego un metodo en el evento Click, me gustaria saber si se pueden pasar parametros hacia el metodo del evento.

Tengo la inicializacion de mi matriz asi:

```
for(int x = 0; x < celdas.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < celdas.GetLength(1); i++)
            {
                celdas[x, i] = new Celda();
                celdas[x, i].SetBounds(i * anchoCelda, x * altoCelda, anchoCelda, altoCelda);
                celdas[x, i].UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
                celdas[x, i].Click +=  evento;
                this.panelMatriz.Controls.Add(celdas[x, i]);
            }
        }
```

el en metodo 'Evento' quiero utilizar la fila y la columna del boton. pero veo la manera de poder mandarlas al metodo.

```
public void evento(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Celda celda = ((Celda)sender);
        MessageBox.Show(celda.Destapada+"");
    }
```

un ejemplo, que al oprimir el boton que me muestre la fila y la columna donde este se encuentra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En principio no se pueden añadir argumentos al manejador de un evento `Click`, básicamente porque no eres tu el que *levanta* el evento, con lo que en ningún caso podrías mandarle ningún argumento. Si fuera un evento personalizado, no habría ningun problema.

Dicho esto,en realidad si hay una forma, pero te la mostraré luego después de analizar otras posibilidades.

Un método que se utilizaba antiguamente era usar la propiedad `Tag` que tienen todos los controles. Esta propiedad admite cualquier `object`,con lo que se puede usar para almacenar información en el propio boton (voy a usar tu ejemplo de pasar la fila y columna del botón):

```
celdas[x, i] = new Celda();
celdas[x, i].Tag=string.Format("{0},{1}",x,i);
...
```

De esta manera,en tu manejador del evento podrías simplemente obtener los datos del `Tag`:

```
Celda celda = ((Celda)sender);
string[] datos=celda.Tag.ToString().Split(',');
int fila=int.Parse(datos[0]);
int columna=int.Parse(datos[1]);
```

Otra posibilidad es que el nombre del botón contuviera el dato que deseas pasar. Por ejemplo, `celdas[x, i].Name= string.Format("Boton{0}{1}",x,i);`

Ahora vamos a una manera de realmente poder pasar argumentos al evento de una manera muy cómoda:

```
celdas[x, i].Click += (sendr, EventArgs) => { evento(sendr, EventArgs, x,i); };
```

De esta manera tus argumentos se añaden al evento, solo tendrías que modificar el manejador asi:

```
public void evento(object sender, EventArgs e,int fila, int columna)
{
    Celda celda = ((Celda)sender);
    MessageBox.Show(celda.Destapada+"");
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda!, me ha sido muy util, apenas ayer empece a aprender este lenguaje, y veo que tiene varios truquillos.

Comment: @AlexisRodriguez pues mucho ánimo y aqui estaremos para resolver las dudas que te vayan surgiendo :)