# hay sobrecarga para 'OnKeyDownHandler' coincide con el delegado 'KeyEventHandler'

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Tengo el siguiente método que tiene el evento OnKeyDownHandler y solo le puedo mandar dos parámetros y yo le quiero mandar una lista también(FileInformation FilesList)

```
private void OnKeyDownHandler(object sender, FileInformation FilesList, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Return)
        {
            TextBox tb = ((TextBox)sender);
            new ConnectorCfdiTool.ViewModel.MainToolVM().BuscarCommand(tb.Text, FilesList);
        }
    }
```

Asi lo tengo en el xaml

```
<TextBox Name="UserInput" LostFocus="UserInput_LostFocus" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="565,35,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="191" KeyDown="OnKeyDownHandler" />
```

Comment: No, no existe ninguna sobrecarga para ese evento. La pregunta es..para que quieres pasarle la lista? Imagino que esa lista la tienes en algún objeto en tu viewmodel, con lo que debes tener acceso a ella. Deberías aclarar de todas maneras de donde viene `FilesList` para poder indicarte una solución mas ajustada. Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y asi ganar tu primera medalla, asi como repasar [ask] para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta.

Comment: Relacionado (aunque para winforms, alguna de las soluciones es aplicable aqui como bien dice @Einer en su respuesta): https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/102688/15301

Answer (score 1):

La asignatura del metodo `KeyDown` solo acepta 2 parametros que son el Object sender y el evento que seria `KeyEventArgs`. Por lo que el delegado **debe** de tener la misma asignatura del evento sino te lanzara un error.

Lo que puedes hacer es utilizar la propiedad `Tag` del control y asignarle el objeto `FileInformation` y luego obtenerlo en la ejecucion del evento.

Para asignarlo seria asi:

```
UserInput.Tag = fileInfoObj;
```

Entonces en tu evento para obtener la referencia del `FileInformation` solo tendrias que convertir la propiedad `Tag` a `FileInformation`:

```
private void OnKeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Return)
        {
            TextBox tb = ((TextBox)sender);
            FileInformation info = tb.Tag as FileInformation;
            new ConnectorCfdiTool.ViewModel.MainToolVM().BuscarCommand(tb.Text, info);
        }
    }
```

O hacer el objeto privado en la clase y obtener la referencia cuando se ejecute el metodo. Por ejemplo:

```
public class MainWindow : Window
{
    private FileInformation fileInfo;
    public MainWindow()
    {
      //...
      this.fileInfo = ObtenerFileInfo();
    }

    private void OnKeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Return)
        {
            TextBox tb = ((TextBox)sender);
            new ConnectorCfdiTool.ViewModel.MainToolVM().BuscarCommand(tb.Text, fileInfo);
        }
    }
}
```